# How to export a directory list from command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, export

I have a folder full of media that I want to export to a list (csv, doc, xml, whatever...).  When I navigate in Command Prompt to that folder, I can use `dir` to display the files in that directory.  I want to export that list.  How can I do this from command prompt?

Also is there an alternative way (built-in) to do it without command prompt?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
dir > textfile.txt
```

will export (pipe) it to a plain text file. You can do whatever you want with it afterwards.

If you wish to append, use two >>'s

```
dir >> textfile.txt
```

If you wish the file to be in another directory, just use

```
dir > c:\temp\textfile.txt
```

Without timestamp

```
dir/b
```

for example ?

Comment: can I append to that file? and how do i define the location if i don't want it to be in that directory? Also, can I get the file to display the results without timestamp?

Comment: How to do reverse of this? Having a list in the text file and only those files form a mixed bag folder?

Answer (score 1):

Easy!

dir > list.txt

Answer (score 0):

Try that utility
[File Names Export](http://filenames.bghot.com)

It is very small and requires no installation.

Comment: Please add some summary, the link might break any time.